# Estilização de views - Laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

Por padrão do Laravel, a view `welcome.blade.php` vem com a estilização na própria view e não em um arquivo separado.

Gostaria de saber se essa prática de estilização da view no mesmo arquivo é correta ou deve-se estilizar separadamente.

Comment: Amigo, isso é subjetivo. Cada caso é um caso. Geralmente usa-se um arquivo CSS separado, para facilitar a organização. Agora, você precisa entender que a view `welcome` que vem no Laravel **é só um exemplo** pra mostrar que o framework funciona. Não se trata do padrão a ser seguido no desenvolvimento.

Answer (score -1):

Existem três tipos de folha de estilo *CSS* possíveis para utilização em projetos WEB, vou falar um pouco sobre cada e ao final poderá conferir qual melhor opção pra você usar nos projetos (caso já conheça os detalhes de casa, pode pular pro final da resposta).

**Estilo inline**

É quando os estilos CSS são aplicados diretamente dentro da tag de abertura de um elemento HTML. No entanto, este tipo de uso das CSS não é recomendado e encontra-se em desuso pelos desenvolvedores WEB. Veja um exemplo de utilização deste tipo de estilo:

```
<div  style=“background-color:blue;   color: red;   width:300px;  height:200px;”>
    <h1>...</h1> 
    <p>...</p> 
    <p>...</p> 
 </div>
```

**Estilo incorporado**

O estilo incorporado também não é o mais indicado e recomendado, uma vez que estilos escritos desta forma ficam restritos a um único documento, não sendo possível a sua reutilização em outras páginas do projeto WEB.

Neste método, você declara a folha de estilo diretamente dentro da seção head do documento HTML, utilizando o elemento style. Veja um exemplo da utilização deste tipo de estilo:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <style type="text/css"> 
            h2 {color:#000;} 
        </style> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <h2>Título Secundário da Página</h2> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

**Estilo externo**

Este tipo de uso de CSS em documentos HTML é o mais indicado e recomendado. Neste tipo, os códigos CSS ficam em um documento externo ao documento HTML, separando assim as camadas de estrutura e apresentação do projeto WEB.

Existem duas formas de incorporar folhas de estilos *CSS* externa ao documento WEB:

**1. Linkadas**

Para o tipo de estilo CSS externo linkado, usa-se o elemento link para incorporar o documento CSS externo ao documento HTML. O elemento link deve ser usado dentro da seção head do documento HTML.

Exemplo:

```
<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/estilos.css" /> 
</head>
```

**2. Importadas**

O tipo de estilo das CSS importadas funciona igualmente ao tipo de estilo das CSS linkadas. O que difere aqui é somente a forma com que isto é feito, uma vez que, neste caso, é usada a diretiva @import dentro do elemento style, na seção head do documento HTML. Exemplo:

```
<head> 
    <style type=“text/css”> 
        @import url("css/estilos.css") screen, projection; 
    </style> 
</head>
```

---

O uso de folhas de estilos externas para declaração de propriedades css é uma das práticas que vem sendo ressaltada e com objetivo: propriedades declaradas de forma “inline” dificultam a manutenção de website, deixam o código carregado de informações não relevantes para mecanismos de busca e para leitores de tela além de, devido este tipo de declaração ter maior relevância na renderização realizada pelos browsers, o que é declarado “inline” vai sobrescrever o que foi declarado nas folhas externas, fazendo com que você se obrigue a utilizar hacks, ou seja, um “conserto” atrás de outro.

Para estruturação inicial de uma interface, podemos criar uma folha de estilos com as propriedades básicas (diagramação de sustentação dos 3 principais elementos), reset nas pré-formatações de alguns elementos e declaração dos estilos dos elementos de repetição do projeto (elementos de topo, menus, breadcrumbs, etc). Esta folha de estilo, por exemplo, poderia ser chamada de: *estrutura.css*.

Para as demais páginas, além da “home”, caso seu projeto seja um projeto de médio a grande porte (websites institucionais, e-commerces e portais) uma dica é o uso de, além da folha de estruturação, uma folha para cada página com suas respectivas propriedades. Por exemplo: *home.css, noticias.css, empresa.css*, etc.